# Outside Library Callbacks in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to make the transition from regular js to angular and I'm getting strange results when I'm using the google places library (and I'm assuming it would be the same with any other asynchronous callback).

Here's the code:

```
var sparkApp = angular.module('sparkApp',[]);

sparkApp.controller('GooglePlacesListCtrl', function GooglePlacesListCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.places = [
        {'name': 'Nexus S',
            'formatted_address': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
        {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
            'formatted_address': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
        {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
            'formatted_address': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
    ];

    // ***
    // **** THIS IS TIED TO AN NG-CLICK
    // ***
    $scope.gmapSearchButtonClicked = function ()
    {
        var query = $("#location_search").val();
        console.log(getMapRadius());
        var request = {
            location: map.getCenter(),
            radius: getMapRadius(),
            query: query
        };

        service.textSearch(request, $scope.searchCallback);
    }

    $scope.searchCallback = function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            // ***
            // **** THIS IS NOT WORKING - IS IT BECAUSE $SCOPE IS IN AN ASYNC CALLBACK?
            // **** IT ALSO SHOWS UP IN CONSOLE CORRECTLY
            // ***
            $scope.places = [{'name': 'Test Scenario',
                    'formatted_address': 'New Stuff'}];
            console.log($scope.places);
        }
    }
});
```

Basically the problem is that my places are not being updated in the template. They load fine at the beginning (with all the nexus stuff), but after I click search (calling gmapSearchButtonClicked), and the callback gets fired then nothing gets updated, even though everything is displayed correctly in console. What's even more odd to me is that if I click search again then the template gets updated with the new data. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Basically the problem was that the changes to the places array were not being applied since the callback is from another library. The solution was wrapping it in $apply like this:

```
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.places = [{'name': 'New',
                'formatted_address': 'New Stuff'}];
            console.log($scope.places);
        });
```

Here's a great full explanation: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html